# Ask for confirmation AFTER upload

Tags: php, ajax

I'm uploading images with AJAX and I'm looking for a way to have the processupload.php making the file ready, then ask back to the index.html for a confirmation, and first after getting the confirmation, write the file to the server and DB.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible, once you've uploaded the file in PHP you either save it or lose it. Best you could do would be to move it to a temporary location and purge it after so long if it's not accepted.

Comment: How about I look it up on my crystal ball and answer you?

Comment: Where is the file in the meantime? Somewhere in the internet pipe between the user and the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't upload a file to limbo. It's either on the server or it isn't.

The best workaround I know of for this is to save it to the server, then delete it if the user decides not to confirm within a designated time period.

Presumably your application has a database, so just add a column for `confirmed`, default to `0` and don't display the image anywhere unless `confirmed = 1`.